# How to fix this WooCommerce / WordPress error?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

[template error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR8x9.png)

How to fix this error on WooCommerce my account page?
Is there any easy way to fix this?

WooCommerce plugin:
electro multivendor e-commerce theme

Comment: Can you turn on the debug from wp-config it seems your footer is not being rendered which means whole structure is not in place, if you can share the URl instead of Image that will explain a lot better what exactly going on here.

Comment: http://209.97.167.115/my-account/

Comment: no brother footer is good

Answer (score 0):

tag added in this page, you need to remove this from editor or by going into theme files. 
As you can see at top of the woocommerce div.

[image]